# connect to windows from ec2 via vpn

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

I am not sure if I should be asking this kind of question on stackoverflow, so if not please be kind and point me in the right direction.

I am trying to connect my ec2 ubuntu 12.04 to a windows server via VPN. I followed the [client setup here](http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/vpn/) and that shows the following in ifconfig:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.0.3.105  P-t-P:10.0.3.100  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1396  Metric:1
          RX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:3151 (3.1 KB)  TX bytes:126 (126.0 B)
```

which I think means its up. But I can't connect to the mysql db on a local IP (within the VPN). I can connect from my mac at home but not from the ec2 server.

My question is, what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of your firewall policy in Amazon, which can be blocking your access from it to Windows.